# Does it posible to have Partial form,when multiple Models managed in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that managed multiple models,i treid to use Partial form for edit and new . when i want to create a record i couldn't change the name of submit button to 'mmmm' via this code:

```
<%= form_for(@word) do |w| %>
<%= render :partial => 'form',:locals => {:w =>w,:submit_lable =>'mmmm'} %>
<% end %>
```

when i tried to edit one record of table i.e record 2 from Table A ,Record 2 from Table B and Table C are too appeare in my form how can i avoid these?
code for edit:

```
def edit
        @word=Word.find(params[:id])
        @verb=Verb.find(params[:id])
        @adjektiv=Adjektiv.find(params[:id])
        @adverb =Adverb.find(params[:id])
  end
```

and this is my code in my partial form:

```
<html>


<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nomen</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Verb</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Adjektiv</a> </li>
       <li><a href="#tabs-4">Adverb</a> </li>
     </ul>
     <div id="tabs-1">
       <table >
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Artikel :
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <%= w.label :Artikel ,'der' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'der',:checked =>false%>
            <%= w.label :Artikel ,'die' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'die',:checked =>true %>
            <%= w.label :Artikel ,'das' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'das',:checked =>false %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Neues Wort:
          </td>
          <td>
             <%= w.text_field :Name ,:size => '31*45'%>
          </td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Synonome :
          </td>
          <td>
             <%= w.text_field :syn ,:size => '31*45'%>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Bedeutung :
          </td>
          <td>
             <%=  w.text_area :bedeutung , :size =>'30*45' %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
              Beispiel :
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= w.text_field :beispiel ,:size => '31*45' %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Kommentar:
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= w.text_area :kommentar ,:size =>'30*45' %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <%= w.submit 'Hinfügen' %>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
       <%= fields_for (@verb) do |v| %>
           <div id="tabs-2">
                         <table>
                           <tr>
                             <td align="right">
                               Das Verb :
                             </td>
                             <td>
                               <%= v.text_field  :name %>
                             </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td>
                               Hilfsverb :
                             </td>
                             <td align="center">
                                 <%= v.label :hverb ,'Sein' %><%= v.radio_button :hverb,'Sein',:checked =>false%>
                                 <%= v.label :hverb ,'haben' %><%= v.radio_button :hverb,'haben',:checked =>true %>
                                 <%= v.label :hverb ,'beide' %><%= v.radio_button :hverb,'beide',:checked =>false %>
                              </td>
                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                             <td align="right">
                               Synonome :
                             </td>
                             <td>
                               <%= v.text_field  :syn %>
                             </td>
                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                             <td align="right">
                               Stammenform :
                             </td>
                             <td>
                               <%= v.text_field :stmform%>
                             </td>

                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td align="right">
                                Bedeutung :
                             </td>
                             <td>
                               <%= v.text_field :bedeutung  %>
                             </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td align="right">
                               Beispiel :
                             </td>
                             <td>
                               <%= v.text_area :beispiel ,:size => '23*45' %>
                             </td>
                             <tr>
                             <td align="right">
                               kommentar :
                             </td>
                             <td>
                               <%= v.text_area :kommentar ,:size => '23*45' %>
                             </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td align="right">
                               Präposition :
                             </td>
                             <td>
                               <%= v.text_field :prep %>
                             </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td>
                                   <%= w.submit 'Hinfügen' %>
                             </td>
                           </tr>
                         </table>
             </div>
           <% end %>
             <div id="tabs-3">
               <%= fields_for (@adjektiv) do |a| %>
               <table>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Adjektiv :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <%= a.text_field :name %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Bedeutung :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <%=  a.text_field :bedeutung %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Synonome :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <%= a.text_field :syn %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                     Komperativform :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <%=  a.text_field :kom %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                        <%= w.submit 'Hinfügen' %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
               </table>

              <% end %>
             </div>
       <div id="tabs-4">
               <%= fields_for (@adverb) do |av| %>
               <table>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Adverb :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <%= av.text_field :name %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Bedeutung :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <%=  av.text_field :bedeutung %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Synonome :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <%= av.text_field :syn %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                        <%= w.submit 'Hinfügen' %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
               </table>

              <% end %>
             </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

and this is my **controller**

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController
  def new
         @word=Word.new
         @verb=Verb.new
         @adjektiv=Adjektiv.new
         @adverb=Adverb.new
  end
  def create
    @word=Word.create(params[:word])
    @verb=Verb.create(params[:verb])
    @adjektiv=Adjektiv.create(params[:adjektiv])
    @adverb=Adverb.create(params[:adverb])

    if @word.save || @verb.save || @adjektiv ||  @adverb
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def index
        @word=Word.find(:all)
        @verb=Verb.find(:all)
        @adjektiv=Adjektiv.find(:all)
        @adverb =Adverb.find(:all)
  end
  def edit
        @word=Word.find(params[:id])
        @verb=Verb.find(params[:id])
        @adjektiv=Adjektiv.find(params[:id])
        @adverb =Adverb.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @word =Word.find(params[:id])
    if @word.update_attributes(params[:word])  ||   @verb.update_attributes(params[:verb])  || @adjektiv.update_attributes(params[:adjektiv]) || @adverb.update_attributes(params[:adverb])
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      redirect_to :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

thnk you for your helps

Comment: Could you post the contents of the form partial?

Comment: Thank#s James,I did it.i edited my Post :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the code for your partial.  You seem to have 2 questions, so I'll answer them individually.

#### "when i want to create a record i couldn't change the name of submit button to 'mmmm'"

OK, so I see you're passing in a local variable to your partial:

```
:submit_lable =>'mmmm'
```

But your submit button is inserted with the following code:

```
<%= w.submit 'Hinfügen' %>
```

Passing in the local variable `:submit_lable` won't set the label of the submit button straight away, all it does is create a variable in the partial called `submit_lable` that you can use to accomplish that with this line of code:

```
<%= w.submit submit_lable %>
```

#### when i tried to edit one record of table i.e record 2 from Table A ,Record 2 from Table B and Table C are too appeare in my form how can i avoid these?

The way you've written your partial, it doesn't look like a partial.  A partial should be a chunk of view code with a well-defined purpose.  It should help you adhere to the DRY principle, and thus you shouldn't have repeated code in there.  You also shouldn't have `<html>..</html>` tags in your partial because it's supposed to represent a part of a complete HTML page, not the whole thing, and HTML tags inside a HTML body is not valid or sensible HTML.  It actually looks like you're writing a layout, so you should have a think about how your page is supposed to fit together and move the structure around those form tags into your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file.

Have a read of the Rails Guides sections on [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) and [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#overview-how-the-pieces-fit-together).  It talks about local variables and general guidelines for using partials and layouts.

*Anyway*, to answer your question: the reason you're seeing all the other forms for your various models is because inside your partial, you have forms for all those models.  You're accessing the records for each model using `params[:id]` and displaying them all at once, in tabs it seems.

This isn't pretty, and it's not easy to deal with.  Really you should be dealing with the models one at a time.

The `edit` action in your controller should be dealing with a single model.  You should have a controller for each of your models, so in your `WordsController`, for instance, you would have:

```
def edit
    @word = Word.find(params[:id])
end
```

Same goes for the rest of them.  I'm not too sure what your form is doing, but I'm guessing  the first div contains the form you're wanting to use for `@word`.  In this case, your partial `_form.html.erb` might be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Artikel :</td>
      <td align="center">
        <%= w.label :Artikel ,'der' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'der',:checked =>false%>
        <%= w.label :Artikel ,'die' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'die',:checked =>true %>
        <%= w.label :Artikel ,'das' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'das',:checked =>false %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Neues Wort:</td>
      <td><%= w.text_field :Name ,:size => '31*45'%></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td align="right">Synonome :</td>
      <td><%= w.text_field :syn ,:size => '31*45'%></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="right">Bedeutung :</td>
      <td><%= w.text_area :bedeutung , :size =>'30*45' %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="right">Beispiel :</td>
      <td><%= w.text_field :beispiel ,:size => '31*45' %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kommentar:</td>
      <td><%= w.text_area :kommentar ,:size =>'30*45' %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><%= w.submit submit_lable %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I'm not sure how having all the forms in tabs on the same page can work - how does switching to a different model with the same ID in the database help you?  I'd recommend you ditch the tabs.  If I'm nor understanding the purpose of the tabs and they're required, try using Ajax to fetch the form content if and when it is required.

Sorry for the long post, but I hope it helps somewhat.  There's not really a straight-forward answer for the 2nd part, as you'll have to do a bit of reading and thinking for yourself to work out the best solution!  Do have a read about rendering, layouts and partials.  Rails has some powerful tools to help make your life easy, so it's really worth getting to know what's at your disposal so you don't make things hard for yourself :).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer james. i learnd many things.you mean that i should for each Model have a controller?but how can i put these controller in one form. i used Fields_for but i think,this statement work when i have one controller with many Models.Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, ideally for each individual model you will have a controller that handles the CRUD actions for it.  However, if for a given model you only create, read, update or delete it through another (parent) model, then *maybe* you don't need a controller for it.

fields_for is really for nested forms, i.e. a model in a model.  Being as your models don't seem to be nested like that, you should be using form_for.

However, you'd need to tell me how your models work, what relationships they have, before I can offer advice for your situation.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooo much James :) first Sorry for my bad English :( I do a  small project to learn RoR. my project is about German language( that save the German words). I have three Tables (Word for Nammen, Adverb for adverbs,Adjektiv for Adjectivs and Adverb for Adverbs) of course in my scnario(thst is not optimal) there is no realation between Tables.I have one form that user can add adverb OR adjective or....(i use accordion and each one has a tab in accordion) i have only one Controller that i add to my post.without problem i can add records but when i want to edit one of them an ..

Comment: Glad I could help!  Check out my answer to this question for some tips on learning Ruby and Rails. I'm still learning too, it's a fun journey, so keep it up, be persistent, and most of all enjoy it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296515/best-ruby-language-guide-tutorial-for-rails/7296653#7296653

Comment: that was fantastic,have you no idea for my problem James? :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the question you ended your comment with.  With the layout you've chosen there will be no problem adding records.  To edit, why don't you just display a single form?  It doesn't make sense from a UI perspective to display the edit forms for 3 other models with the same ID as the one the user intended to edit - they don't want to edit any other records but the one they chose to edit.  That way the your problem should go away.  Let me know if I'm misunderstanding your question, however.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3156/discussion-between-jamesds-and-babak-bst)